# Will repeatedly defining a string literal constant use more memory?

Tags: java, static

**Approach 1**: Say I have a constant in 500 (five hundred) classes like this:

```
public static final String NAME = "CHICAGO";
```

**Approach 2**: Or I can just store it in one class and import that class in those 500 classes and invoke it directly `Constants.NAME`.

```
public class Constants {
private Constants() {   }
public static final String NAME = "CHICAGO";
}
```

Can someone please answer me what is the memory footprint of either approaches? Approach A will take more memory? Or Approach B will take equivalent memory?

This question is only about memory footprint.

Comment: The memory footprint isn't worth worrying about. The maintenance overhead of duplicating the same value in 500 places is what you should be worried about.

Comment: Can you please not turn the subject into something else. So you are saying, approach1 will take more memory than approach 2?

Comment: Don't let me put words in your mouth @AndyTurner, but what I get from that comment is, the memory footprint is *immaterial*.  You have other problems with 500 repeated declarations of the same constant.

Comment: @Makoto please tell me if approach 1 will take more memory than approach 2??

Comment: Approach 1 (don't know what approach A is) will take more memory, i.e. 500 references to the same (pooled) string. A reference can be 4 bytes or 8 bytes, so 500 * 4 = 2000 bytes, i.e. not worth considering.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Of all the things to be concerned about taking memory, a seven-letter string ranks firmly at the bottom of the list.  Do you have a memory problem in your application?  Have you profiled it to see where the most memory usage is coming in?

Comment: @Makoto or, have you a accidentally spelt it CHICGAO in one place. (Btw, yes, what you said to my previous comment).

Comment: lmfao @Makoto, just please tell me which approach will take more memory. I cannot go deep into issue.

Comment: @AndyTurner:  I'd imagine that this would be something that unit testing would catch, but given that there's already five-hundred declarations of such a constant, my faith isn't that high on this, so I agree with and concede to your point.

Comment: @FarazDurrani The reason people are answering off-topic of the question, is because the question is asking the wrong question. Their points are very valid, i.e. replicated source code is a much bigger issue than memory use, in this case.

Comment: @FarazDurrani:  There's nothing to really elaborate on - you need to profile your application.  We can't help you with that since at an initial pass, you have other problems with this single snippet of code and its intended usage, and memory is most certainly ***not*** one of them.  **Please profile your code.** We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: @Makoto maybe, but that requires you to meaningfully test all 500 places.

Comment: okay thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @zlakad What does any of this have to do with enums? Whether the `public static final String` is in a class or enum makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @Andreas, well the very first thing I saw was the `public class Constants {` declaration. I didn't even read further more

Comment: @zlakad still, what does that have to do with enums? You can only declare constants in an enum if they have the same type, and even then, an enum value for PI is far more cumbersome than a double.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I now read it all, my mistake - deleting the comment

Comment: @zlakad Wow, because the first line was `public class Constants`, you couldn't be bothered to read the next 2 lines?!?

Comment: @Andreas, yep, I suppose I was too lazy. Anyway, sorry about that

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372563/add-a-close-reason-for-half-formed-profiling-questions-and-allow-for-gold-badge)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With Approach 1, when each of the 500 classes loads
 (a) You will have 500 references pointing to `CHICAGO` which is redundant
 (b) If value changes later on you will need to change it everywhere

Approach 2 will be better as you will be defining the line 
`public static final String NAME = "CHICAGO";` 
just once rather than having it 500 times.

To summarize :

In both cases, we will have just one `CHICAGO` in the literal pool (because of interning), but with Approach 1 we will have 500 unnecessary references to the same.

Comment: Please stick to memory footprint aspect of declaring a same constant in 500 class or in 1 class.

Comment: I would imagine that String interning would actually reduce the likelihood that the same string is declared more than say, a handful of times.

Comment: The memory footprint hardly matters @FarazDurrani, what does matter is a very glaring issue with approach 1

Comment: @Makoto : True. Just to add one more point, each of the 500 classes would have a reference `NAME` to `CHICAGO` which is redundant.

Comment: I just downvoted purely because you haven't provided any evidence that the answer you've given here is true. (I don't know enough about the optimisation powers of the Java compiler to know either way, but a bare assertion of what the answer is in response to a question with only two possible answers just plain isn't useful; why should anyone believe you without some kind of substantiating evidence?)